# Add a row to a dataframe that repeats a row and replaces 2 entries

Tags: r, dplyr

I want to add rows to a dataframe (or tibble) as part of a data entry project. I need to:

1. Find one row that holds a specific value in one column (obsid)
2. Duplicate that row. However, replace the value in column "word".
3. Append the new row to the dataframe

I want to write a function that makes it easy. When I write the function, it won't add the new rows. I can print out the answer. But it won't alter the basic dataframe

If I do it without a function it works as well.

Why won't the function add the row?

```
df <- tibble(obsid = c("a","b" , "c", "d"), b=c("a", "a", "b", "b"), word= c("what", "is", "the", "answer"))
df$main <- 1

addrow <- function(id, newword) {
  rowtoadd <- df %>%
    filter(obsid== id &  main==1) %>% 
    mutate(word=replace(word, main==1, newword)) %>% 
    mutate(main=replace(main, word==newword, 0)) 
  df <- bind_rows(df, rowtoadd) 
  print(rowtoadd) 
  print(filter(df, df$obsid== id))}

addrow("a", "xxx")
```

Comment: Functions need to return values--in this case the modified data frame. Make the last line of your function `df` or `return(df)`, and then you can do df <- addrow("a", "xxx")`. I'd also recommend having the function take `df` as an argument so you can use it no matter the name of the data frame...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

R objects usually don't modify itself, you need to warp the result in `return()` to return the modified copy of that dataframe.

Change your function to:

```
df <- tibble(obsid = c("a","b" , "c", "d"), b=c("a", "a", "b", "b"), word= c("what", "is", "the", "answer"))
df$main <- 1

addrow <- function(id, newword) {
    rowtoadd <- df %>%
        filter(obsid== id &  main==1) %>% 
        mutate(word=replace(word, main==1, newword)) %>% 
        mutate(main=replace(main, word==newword, 0)) 
    df <- bind_rows(df, rowtoadd)
    return(df)
}
```

```
> addrow("a", "xxx")
# A tibble: 5 x 4
  obsid b     word    main
  <chr> <chr> <chr>  <dbl>
1 a     a     what       1
2 b     a     is         1
3 c     b     the        1
4 d     b     answer     1
5 a     a     xxx        0
```